# Parar Form Action com Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

## O que desejo

Eu adiciono campos dinamicamente informando a quantidade de linhas que desejo adicionar. Eu desejo que logo que o usuário clicar para enviar o formulário, eu faça uma verificação usando o Ajax para ver se algum dos dados informados já foram cadastrados. Caso isso seja verdadeiro, ele irá abrir um dialog com as informações dos valores já cadastrados e impedirá o formulário ser redirecionado ao arquivo php.

## O que eu fiz

Cheguei a fazer o script do Ajax que chama um PHP e retorna(caso exista)um array com os dados repetidos. A questão é: Digitei um número novo e outro repetido. O certo seria ele parar o envio do form no exato momento em que ele  verificar todos os campos e achar os já inseridos, mostrando o dialog. Ele até mostra o dialog, mas no mesmo instante ele vai pro arquivo php que faria a inserção no bancoo. Como posso fazer com que ele pare o form caso a variável 'msg', do arquivo Javascript, tenha alguma coisa ?

A função que verifica os dados é a penúltima do arquivo **Javascript**: `$('#formBarcodeId').submit(function (evt) {`.
Eu adicionei para teste a linha  `$("#dialog").prepend("<p><b>teste</p>");` na função `function ShowResults(value, index, ar) {` - que adiciona os valores ao dialog -, e ainda assim o dialog ficou vazio.

## Index

```
    <body>
        <main>
            <header>
                <h1>Ficha de Assinatura de Prestação de Contas</h1>
            </header>

            <div id="dialog" title="Dados Já Inseridos">
            </div>

            <div id="main">
                <div id="content">
                    <input type="text" name="adicionarCamposQtd" id="adicionarCamposQtd" placeholder="Quantidade de novos campos">
                    <button id="adicionarCampo">+ adicionar campo</button>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_GET['erro'])) {
                            $erro = $_GET['erro'];
                            if($erro == 1) {
                                $mensagemDeErro = "Por favor, preencha todos os campos";
                            }
                            else if($erro == 2) {
                                $mensagemDeErro = "Por favor, verifique se os dados informados já não foram cadastrados";
                            }
                            echo "<p id='mensagemErro'>$mensagemDeErro</p>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    <form method="POST" action="gerarpdf.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formBarcode" id="formBarcodeId">
                        <div id="formulario">
                            <select name="mesReferencia1" required>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Mês de Referência</option>
                                <option value="02">Feveiro/Março</option>
                                <option value="04">Abril/Maio</option>
                                <option value="06">Junho/Julho</option>
                                <option value="08">Agosto/Setembro</option>
                                <option value="10">Outubro/Novembro</option>
                                <option value="12">Dezembro/Janeiro</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="anoReferencia1" required>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Ano de Referência</option>
                                <?php 
                                    $data = date("Y");
                                    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
                                        echo '<option value="'.substr($data,2,2).'">'.$data.'</option>';
                                        $data++;
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                            <br/>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Código da Entidade" maxlength="5" name="numeroDocumento1" required/>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="criancaIdade1" id="criancaLabel1" value="1"><label for="criancaLabel1">Criança</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="idosoIdade1" id="idosoIdade1" value="2"><label for="idosoIdade1">Idoso</label>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="quantidadeCampos" value="1" id="quantidadeCampos">
                        <input type="submit" value="Gerar Código" name="submitBarcode" id="submitBarcodeId" required/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
```

## Javascript

```
$(function () {
    //Quando clicar em submit do form ele verifica os campos já inseridos
    $('#formBarcodeId').submit(function (evt) {
        var valoresFormulario = $('#formBarcodeId').serialize();
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'verificaAjax.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: valoresFormulario,
            success : function(msg){
                $(function() {
                    $("#dialog").empty();
                    msg.forEach(ShowResults);
                    $("#dialog").css('overflow','scroll');
                    $("#dialog").dialog({
                        dialogClass: "no-close",
                        resizable: false,
                        minWidth: 700,
                        minHeight: 400,
                        maxHeight: 600,
                        draggable:false,
                        modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                Ok: function() {
                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                }
                            }
                    });
                });
            } 
        });
    });

    // Função para retornar os valores
    function ShowResults(value, index, ar) {
        $("#dialog").prepend("<p><b>Número da Entidade</b>: " + value['codigo_entidade']+ "</p><br/>");
        if(value['codigo_projeto'] == 1) {
            $("#dialog").prepend("<p><b>Projeto</b>: Criança</p>"); 
        }
        else if(value['codigo_projeto'] == 2){
            $("#dialog").prepend("<p><b>Projeto</b>: Idoso</p>"); 
        }
        $("#dialog").prepend("<p><b>Ano: </b>: " + value['ano_ref'] + "</p>");
        $("#dialog").prepend("<p><b>Mês:</b> " + value['mes_ref'] + "</p>");
        $("#dialog").prepend("<p><b>Caminho do Arquivo</b>: " + value['caminho'] + "</p>");
    }

});
```

## verificaAjax.php

```
$bancoDeDados = new Bd();

$mesReferencia = $_POST["mesReferencia1"];    
$anoReferencia = $_POST["anoReferencia1"];

// Verificador de primeiro valor consulta
$verificador = 0;

//Caso o campo de quantidade não existir. Ou seja, só temos uma linha
if(empty($_POST["quantidadeCampos"])) {
    $numeroDocumento = $_POST["numeroDocumento1"];

    if(!empty($_POST["criancaIdade1"])) {
        $mensagemResultado = $bancoDeDados->selectEtiquetaBD($numeroDocumento,$anoReferencia,$mesReferencia,1);
        $verificador+=1;
    }
    if(!empty($_POST["idosoIdade1"])) {
        //Verifica se esse é o primeiro valor procurado, para caso não, então fundir os arrays
        if ($verificador == 0) {
            $mensagemResultado = $bancoDeDados->selectEtiquetaBD($numeroDocumento,$anoReferencia,$mesReferencia,2);
            $verificador+=1;
        }
        else {
            $resultadoConsulta = $bancoDeDados->selectEtiquetaBD($numeroDocumento,$anoReferencia,$mesReferencia,2);
            $mensagemResultado = array_merge($mensagemResultado,$resultadoConsulta);
        }
    }
}
else {
    $limiteFor = $_POST["quantidadeCampos"];
    for($contadorFor = 1; $contadorFor <= $limiteFor; $contadorFor++) {

        //Recebe o número do documento
        $numeroDocumento = $_POST["numeroDocumento$contadorFor"];

        if(!empty($_POST["criancaIdade$contadorFor"])) {
            if ($verificador == 0) {
                $mensagemResultado = $bancoDeDados->selectEtiquetaBD($numeroDocumento,$anoReferencia,$mesReferencia,1);
                $verificador = 1;
            }
            else {
                $resultadoConsulta = $bancoDeDados->selectEtiquetaBD($numeroDocumento,$anoReferencia,$mesReferencia,1);
                $mensagemResultado = array_merge($mensagemResultado,$resultadoConsulta);
            }
        }
        if(!empty($_POST["idosoIdade$contadorFor"])) {
            //Verifica se esse é o primeiro valor procurado, para caso não, então fundir os arrays
            if ($verificador == 0) {
                $mensagemResultado = $bancoDeDados->selectEtiquetaBD($numeroDocumento,$anoReferencia,$mesReferencia,2);
                $verificador = 1;
            }
            else {
                $resultadoConsulta = $bancoDeDados->selectEtiquetaBD($numeroDocumento,$anoReferencia,$mesReferencia,2);
                $mensagemResultado = array_merge($mensagemResultado,$resultadoConsulta);
            }
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($mensagemResultado);
```

Comment: O PHP está funcionando? Digo isso porque a gente não tem como testar essa parte. Se o PHP estiver funcionando ok, seria o caso de você postar um exemplo do output `json_encode($mensagemResultado)`. . . . Dúvida: se já faz a verificação por AJAX, porque não faz o `submit` por AJAX também?

Comment: @brasofilo Agora sim - a tabela estava errado. Ele agora retorna os dados certinhos, mas um dos problemas persiste. Vamos dizer que eu coloquei um valor que não está inserido no banco e na linha de baixo um que existe. Quando eu clico no submit ele ainda continua o submit - eu queria que ele parasse o submit e mostrasse o dialog.Tentei usar um if(msg != null) { para só travar se essa variável tivesse algo dentro, mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu troquei o `submit` por `button`, assim podendo controlar melhor a ação de envio do formulário. Feito isso foi só mudar o evento para quando clicar no botão.

```
<input type="button" value="Gerar Código" name="submitBarcode" id="submitBarcode" required/>


//Quando clicar em submit do form ele veifica os campos já inseridos
    $('#submitBarcode').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'verificaAjax.php',
            data: $('#formBarcodeId').serialize(),
            success : function(msg){
                if (msg.status == 0) {
                    $(function() {
                        $("#dialog").empty();
                        //$("#dialog").html("<p>" + msg.errorMsg + "</p>");
                        retorno = msg.errorMsg;
                        retorno.forEach(ShowResults);
                        $("#dialog").dialog({
                            dialogClass: "no-close",
                            resizable: false,
                            minWidth: 700,
                            minHeight: 400,
                            maxHeight: 600,
                            draggable:false,
                            modal: true,
                                buttons: {
                                    Ok: function() {
                                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                    }
                                }
                        });
                    });
                }
                else{
                    $('#formBarcodeId').submit();
                }
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                 alert("Erro no Processamento dos Dados. Entre em contato com o setor de Tecnologia e informe a mensagem abaixo:\n"+xhr.responseText);
            }

        });
    });
```